# How to analyze output in gem5 simulation

Tags: cache, parallels, gem

How can we check the data sharing and parallelism for a benchmark in gem5 simulator.
I have run for 4 cores with 4 threads with 2 level cache where size of L1=4MB and L2=4MB respectively. I  was told to count the number of blocks of each state(M,E,S,I) but I have no idea how.